# USB datalogger ground read isn't zero volts

Tags: voltage, ground, datalogger

Im using NI DAQ USB 6008 datalogger. When I connect A0 (or 1,2 etc..) to ground in single-ended mode it gives 6 mV. Shouldn't it be 0 mV? Is it corrupted or normal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inputs on these are typically covering a +/-10V range and as you may be using a 12 bit input ADC, the resolution will be 20 volts/4096 = 4.88mV.

Given that this is resolution only, accuracy could be double this error quite easily.

In fact on further reading of the data sheet I suspect that the input resolution (single-ended) is only 11 bits. See [this](http://sine.ni.com/nips/cds/view/p/lang/en/nid/201986) - click on data sheet link then click on detailed data sheet link.